# Filtering Lists with A and ( B or C)

Tags: list, filter

Filter = A and ( B or C )

For a sharepoint list, how does one get the above behavior?

For example, the default behavior would be Filter = A and B or C

Specifically, the desiresed filter is EmplyoeeActive = true AND ( Department = "Sales" OR Department = "Marketing" )

My current filter is returning any employee in sales or marketing, regardless of the the EmployeeActive being true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your OR clause must be done first.

Try
Department = "Sales" OR Department = "Marketing" AND EmployeeActive=true

Answer (score 0):

For more info on how filters work in list views then you could look at [this article](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/Understanding-Filters-in-SharePoint-List-Views.aspx) that I wrote for End User SharePoint.

This basically explains (as did Mike for this specific example) that filters are '**grouped in pairs from the beginning**'. Difficult to explain without examples, but hopefully the article linked helps.